# Export shortcuts from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to export shortcuts from Android Studio? For example, if I want to reinstall my OS and I don't want to setup all the shortcuts manually after that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For Android Studio before version 4.x: **File** -> **Export settings**

After version 4.x: **File** -> **Manage IDE Settings** -> **Export Settings**

Select `key maps` only if you just want to save your shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Android Studio version 4.x it's at File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Export Settings...

Comment: This works access JetBrains products. I have successfully exported keymap from PhpStrom and imported into Android Studio for Kotlin development. 

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio Version 4, navigate to:

1. The **File** menu
2. Select **Settings**
3. Click on **Manage IDE Settings**
4. Select **Export Settings**

Please note that, this instruction may not be accurate as of the latest version of Android Studio and the layout of the menu might have changed. It is always recommended to check the official documentation for the current version of the software for accurate instructions.